# What is the correct way to write Excel UDF's so they work on Desktop, Web and Mobile Office

Tags: excel

With the introduction of Excel on Android and iOS, I'm not sure what's the correct method of creating a UDF (User Defined Function) that will work across all versions of the Office 365?

I want my UDF to work on iPad, Android as well as Desktop. What's the official Microsoft way of supporting all of these versions of Office for UDF's?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to support all these platforms. It will work on the Desktop editon of Office.